# How do I find a pointer to a segue (without calling one of the performSegue methods)?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

From within one of my `tableViewControllers` I need to get a pointer to another `tableView` (which is the destination of the segue from this `tableViewController`).  I don't actually want to perform the segue and pull up the new view onto the screen, i simply need a pointer to the `destinationViewController`.

The only place i can seem to find a pointer to this object is through one of the `performSegue` methods...

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SavedTrackingViewController *stvc = (SavedTrackingViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
```

But i cant seem to find a pointer to this segue anywhere else in my view controller.

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: I don't think the segues are available in any api.  Anyway, even if you got hold of an outbound segue, there's little (no) chance the destination view controller is allocated at that point.

Comment: You could use a singleton or another global variable to this without segue.

Comment: The key question is why?  What are you aiming to do with the vc?

Comment: My vc has a number of functions I want to call (non UI related) - these really should be in the Model part of the MVC design, but its easier to just leave them where they are for now and move them to the Model later when i have some spare time to do the refactor.  For now i think I'll just alloc a temporary new VC, call the methods and then release the object.